# hybrid app development using phonegap and ADO.NET

Tags: javascript, css, html, cordova

I'm new to web application development.I want to develop a hybrid application which works for Andriod, iOS and desktop as well using phonegap. I'm thinking of mySQl as the database and ADO.NET layer(web Services) on that which communicates with javascript for sending data to and fro.Is this achievable?

Any other suggestions are also welcomed.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , you this will be achievable as you want to develop hybrid application. Best way for CURD operation in phonegap is JSON